# Incorrect result for the sum of the two lowest numbers in a sorted array

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I want to make a program in C that prints the sum of the two smallest numbers in a given array. The way I tried to solve it is: first, I sort the array with a "bubbleSort" function, and then I just add up the first and second elements in the sorted array (arr[0] + arr[1]). It works fine with many other samples, but the array given in the code example below gives me a completely incorrect result; what is the reason for this?
And, is this a correct solution for my program, or should I change my approach?

```
int main(){
   int arr[] = {2000000000, 2000000000, 2000000000, 2000000000, 2000000000}; //unsorted array
   int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

   bubbleSort(arr, n); //Function to Bubble Sort the given array

   printf("Sorted array: \n"); 
   printArray(arr, n); //prints sorted array, which in this particular case is just the same the original

   int result = arr[0] + arr[1]; // result should be "4000000000"
   printf("Result: %i\n", result); //Result is "-294967296", which is clearly incorrect

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `4000000000` needs 32 bits to be represented in binary. I assume your `int`s have 31 value bits and therefore cannot represent that value (they go up to `2147483647`). Try `unsigned int result = (unsigned)arr[0] + (unsigned)arr[1]` or `long long int result = (long long int)arr[0] + (long long int)arr[1]` (remember to change the conversion specifier in `printf()`)

Comment: If an int is 32 bits on your machine, then you don't need to change the type of the array.  You can just change from `int` (which is the same as `signed int`) to `unsigned` (which is the same as `unsigned int`)  A `int` can only hold numbers up to a max of 2.1 billion but `unsigned` can hold numbers up to 4.2 billion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you are getting is a garbage value. There's a integer overflow. So, use `long int` instead. Like this

```
long int arr[] = {2000000000, 2000000000, 2000000000, 2000000000, 2000000000};
```

Comment: You don't need to change the type of the "given array" :)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I'm making this program for a Codewars kata in C language, but I guess the kata isn't well optimized for C (or, at least, it doesn't expect me to sort the array?), since it asks me to work with arrays of integers and not long integers, yet it puts this array as one of the tests. In 100+ arrays, this one is the only one that I got incorrect

Comment: `long int` will give the same problem as it can also be 32-bit. Use `unsigned` 32-bit type, or `long long`.